# CSS - Centering a footer background image

Tags: css

In my MVC app, I have a footer on each page containing an image. I'd like to center the image if possible. My current CSS looks as follows:

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-150px; /* This puts the footer 100px below the bottom of the page*/
    width:70%;
    height:175px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background-image: url("/Images/Footer/Footer3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

What do I need to add to center the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `background-position` property like:

See also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-150px; /* This puts the footer 100px below the bottom of the page*/
    width:70%;
    height:175px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("/Images/Footer/Footer3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```